# How do I distinguish "plus" 1 and "positive" 1 in statement a=1+1

Tags: antlr4

I have a simple grammar:

```
grammar Test; 

prog: (stat NEWLINE)* ; 
stat: ID '=' expr; 
expr: expr ('*'|'/') expr 
  | expr ('+'|'-') expr 
  | INT 
  | '(' expr ')' 
  ;
NEWLINE : [\r\n]+ ; 
ID : [a-z]+;
NT : ('+'|'-')?[0-9]+ ; 
WS : [ \t]* -> skip;
```

How do I distinguish "plus" 1 and "positive" 1 in statement a=1+1?
I expect as below:

[image]

but I got this error:

[image]

```
error: extraneous input '+1' expecting NEWLINE
```

Comment: Your lexer rule `NT` is going to match before your parser rule `expr` rule does. I would remove or modify `NT` to remove the +/- operators and add them as an alternate in your `expr` rule, or cover it in a new rule that has lower precedence than `expr ('+'|'-') expr`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need parsing context to distinguish between the two.

The Lexer would (in theory) have the option of tokenizing "1+1" as either:

```
INT
"+"
INT
```

or

```
INT
INT
```

but, we have to choose one during tokenization so the tokenizer prioritizes the longest tokens first, so "+1" is a longer token than `+`, and `+1` (INT) it is for the tokenizer.

You need context to distinguish them, and that'll require a Parser rule.

Try:

```
grammar Test
    ;

prog: (stat NEWLINE)*;
stat: ID '=' expr;
expr
    : expr ('*' | '/') expr # MulExpr
    | expr ('+' | '-') expr # AddSubExpr
    | ('+' | '-')? INT      # intExpr
    | '(' expr ')'          # parenExpr
    ;
NEWLINE: [\r\n]+;
ID:      [a-z]+;
INT:     [0-9]+;
WS:      [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

You'll want the sign alternative to be a lower priority than the addition alternative (I've also added alternative labels as that makes things much easier to deal with in your code.

NOTE: I changed the cardinality on your `WS` rule from `*` to `+` (you don't want that rule to match an empty string.